# MongoDB - aggregate and concatenate results to group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have some `items` collection like this:

```
[
    { name: 'item1', description: 'description #1', categories: 'cat_A; cat_B'},
    { name: 'item2', description: 'description #2', categories: 'cat_B'},
    { name: 'item3', description: 'description #3', categories: 'cat_C; cat_B'},
    { name: 'item4', description: 'description #4', categories: 'cat_B; cat_A'},
    { name: 'item5', description: 'description #5', categories: 'cat_B'},
    { name: 'item6', description: 'description #6', categories: 'cat_D'}
]
```

I want to find and filter results by categories. I created mongo query:

```
db.getCollection('items')
    .aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                categories: {$in: [/cat_a/i, /cat_b/i]}
            }
        }, {
            $group: {
                _id: "$categories",
                items: { $push:  { name: "$name", description: '$description' } }
            }
        }
    ])
```

So it returns me this:

```
result : [
    {
        "_id" : "cat_B; cat_C",
        "items" : [
            {
                "name" : "item3",
                "description" : "description #3"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "_id" : "cat_B; cat_A",
        "items" : [
            {
                "name" : "item4",
                "description" : "description #4"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "_id" : "cat_B",
        "items" : [
            {
                "name" : "item2",
                "description" : "description #2"
            },
            {
                "name" : "item5",
                "description" : "description #5"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "_id" : "cat_A; cat_B",
        "items" : [
            {
                "name" : "item1",
                "description" : "description #1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
result : [
    {
        "_id" : "cat_A",
        "items" : [
            {
                "name" : "item1",
                "description" : "description #1"
            },
            {
                "name" : "item4",
                "description" : "description #4"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "_id" : "cat_B",
        "items" : [
            {
                "name" : "item1",
                "description" : "description #1"
            },
            {
                "name" : "item2",
                "description" : "description #2"
            },
            {
                "name" : "item3",
                "description" : "description #3"
            },
            {
                "name" : "item4",
                "description" : "description #4"
            },
            {
                "name" : "item5",
                "description" : "description #5"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is that possible in pure mongo query?

Answer (score 2):

With the aggregation framework you're going to need a mechanism to split the `categories` string into a distinct set but such an operator does not exist yet; the closest you will get is the **[`substr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/)** operator which would require knowing the index of the index position and specified number of characters for the substring to be extracted, which would be near impossible. Hence the recommendation of storing the categories as an array of distinct category names.

--***EDIT***--

Should you want to keep the `categories` field as is then I would suggest you create an extra field that stores the list of categories, then you can run the aggregation pipeline on that field to get the desired result.

Let's use an example to demonstrate the approaches above:

**Changing the schema**

a) *If using MongoDB v3.0 or below:*

```
var bulk = db.items.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    counter = 0;

db.items.find({}).forEach(doc) {
    var categoriesList = doc.categories.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"").split(/\s*;\s*/);
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id })
        .updateOne({ 
            "$set": { "categoriesList": categoriesList } 
        });
    counter++;

    if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.items.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
} 

if (counter % 1000 != 0 ) bulk.execute();
```

b) *If using MongoDB v3.2.X or above:*

```
var cursor = db.items.find({}),
    bulkUpdateOps = [];

cursor.forEach(function(doc){ 
    var categoriesList = doc.categories.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"").split(/\s*;\s*/);
    bulkUpdateOps.push({ 
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
            "update": { "$set": { "categoriesList": categoriesList } }
         }
    });

    if (bulkUpdateOps.length == 1000) {
        db.items.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps);
        bulkUpdateOps = [];
    }
});         

if (bulkUpdateOps.length > 0) db.items.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps);
```

**Running the aggregation on new schema**

```
db.items.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "categoriesList": { "$in": ['cat_A', 'cat_B'] } } },
    { "$unwind": "$categoriesList" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$categoriesList",
            "items": { "$push":  { "name": "$name", "description": '$description' } }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: we could use `split(";")` and `trim` for a small cleanup.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot modify any field in this collection and I need to keep `categories` as a string.

Comment: Then create an extra field that stores the distinct set of categories and you can keep the original categories field as is. When you run the aggregation pipeline you can then `$unwind` and group by the new field.

Comment: I can't do that too. In my case items collection and DB is read only. I think I wll leave simple mongo `.find` method and group data by category after I get response on backend. Thank you for your help.